# In Java variables being stated but then forgotten?

Tags: java, variables, double

I have this Java code. It is a simple little thing where I am trying to get the Occupancy Rate of a hotel by dividing the total number of Occupied rooms but the total number of Rooms. However, when I try to compile the code I get:

```
C:\Users\Jerome\Documents\Computer Concepts and Programming\Lab04\JRGlab04Num07\JRGlab04Num07.java:62: error: variable totalORooms might not have been initialized
            totalORooms += numORooms;
            ^
C:\Users\Jerome\Documents\Computer Concepts and Programming\Lab04\JRGlab04Num07\JRGlab04Num07.java:63: error: variable totalRooms might not have been initialized
            totalRooms += numRooms;
            ^
C:\Users\Jerome\Documents\Computer Concepts and Programming\Lab04\JRGlab04Num07\JRGlab04Num07.java:68: error: variable totalORooms might not have been initialized
        ORate = totalORooms / totalRooms;
                ^
C:\Users\Jerome\Documents\Computer Concepts and Programming\Lab04\JRGlab04Num07\JRGlab04Num07.java:68: error: variable totalRooms might not have been initialized
        ORate = totalORooms / totalRooms;
                              ^
4 errors

Tool completed with exit code 1
```

So Why the heck is it forgetting the variable that I had already stated.

```
import java.util.Scanner; //Needed for Inputting
import java.text.DecimalFormat;//Needed for Rounding

/**
The pourpose of this lab is:
To calculate the occupancy rate of a hotel
by JEROME GERO Lab 04 Number 07
*/

public class JRGlab04Num07
{//Begin Class
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {//Begin Main Method

        //Variables and introduction
        double totalFloors, floor, numRooms, numORooms;
        double totalRooms;
        double totalORooms;
        double ORate;
        System.out.println("Welcome to the Hotel Occupancy Calculator.\nPlease enter the number of floors we will be dealing with:");
        Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);
        DecimalFormat formatter = new DecimalFormat("#0.00");


        totalFloors = keyboard.nextInt();
        floor = 0;

        while(totalFloors < 1)
        {
            System.out.println("No, lets try that again.");
            totalFloors = keyboard.nextInt();
        }

        System.out.println("Okay");


        while(totalFloors > 0)
        {

            ++floor;
            System.out.println("Now enter the number of rooms on floor " + floor);
            numRooms = keyboard.nextDouble();


            while(numRooms < 10){
                System.out.println("The Number of rooms nust be greater than 10.\nPlease enter the number of rooms.");
                numRooms = keyboard.nextDouble();
            }


            System.out.println("Now enter the number of occupied rooms on that floor:");
            numORooms = keyboard.nextDouble();


            while(numORooms > numRooms){
                System.out.println("No, the Number of Occupied rooms can not be more than the number of rooms on this floor.\n" +
                "Please enter that again.");
                numORooms = keyboard.nextDouble();
            }


            totalORooms += numORooms;
            totalRooms += numRooms;
            --totalFloors;

        }

        ORate = totalORooms / totalRooms;

        System.out.println(ORate);

    }//End Main Method
}//End Class
```

Comment: Why are you doing a `nextInt()` for float values? It should be `nextDouble()`.

Comment: whoops! My bad. But that doesn't seem to be affecting it.

Comment: The compiler is telling you that your variables have never been initialized -- they've never been given an initial value. `double totalORooms` just declares that such a variable exists; it doesn't give it an initial value. (The compiler doesn't know what you'd want that initial value be: 0? NaN? Infinity? -Infinity?)

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because the error message completely answers the question posed.

Answer (score 1):

You do not assign a value to totalRooms. The error tells you it has not been initialized.

```
double totalRooms = 0.0;
```

Comment: Thank you. I did not understand what was going on. I am a nooby noob and forgot to give the variables an original value of 0. My bad. Sorry about that.